# JMH error Annotation generator had thrown the exception. java.lang.ClassCastException

Tags: java, java-8, jmh

I am getting error: **Annotation generator had thrown the exception. java.lang.ClassCastException**

```
package org.sample;

import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.Benchmark;
import java.util.EnumSet;


public class MyBenchmark {

    @Benchmark
    public static <E extends Enum<E>> EnumSet<E> test(E param) {
        return null;
    }

}
```

In this benchmark, I have removed most of the code to provide minimum viable example.
Seems this is because of test method signature.

```
I have tried this on JDK8, 13 and 14.
Using JMH (1.23)
OS Ubuntu.
```

Following is the output of the mvn clean install

```
    vipin:/home/vipin/IdeaProjects/jmh/test$ mvn clean install
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$ReflectUtils$1 (file:/usr/share/maven/lib/guice.jar) to method java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$ReflectUtils$1
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
[INFO] Error stacktraces are turned on.
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] --------------------------< org.sample:test >---------------------------
[INFO] Building JMH benchmark sample: Java 1.0
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ test ---
[INFO] Deleting /home/vipin/IdeaProjects/jmh/test/target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ test ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /home/vipin/IdeaProjects/jmh/test/src/main/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.0:compile (default-compile) @ test ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 1 source file to /home/vipin/IdeaProjects/jmh/test/target/classes
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Annotation generator had thrown the exception. java.lang.ClassCastException: class com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$TypeVariableSymbol cannot be cast to class javax.lang.model.element.TypeElement (com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$TypeVariableSymbol is in module jdk.compiler of loader 'app'; javax.lang.model.element.TypeElement is in module java.compiler of loader 'platform')
    at org.openjdk.jmh.generators.annotations.APClassInfo.<init>(APClassInfo.java:71)
    at org.openjdk.jmh.generators.annotations.APParameterInfo.getType(APParameterInfo.java:46)
    at org.openjdk.jmh.generators.core.StateObjectHandler.validateStateArgs(StateObjectHandler.java:142)
    at org.openjdk.jmh.generators.core.BenchmarkGenerator.validateBenchmark(BenchmarkGenerator.java:237)
    at org.openjdk.jmh.generators.core.BenchmarkGenerator.generate(BenchmarkGenerator.java:81)
    at org.openjdk.jmh.generators.BenchmarkProcessor.process(BenchmarkProcessor.java:57)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.callProcessor(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1023)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.discoverAndRunProcs(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:939)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment$Round.run(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1267)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.doProcessing(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1381)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.processAnnotations(JavaCompiler.java:1263)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.compile(JavaCompiler.java:935)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.lambda$doCall$0(JavacTaskImpl.java:104)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.handleExceptions(JavacTaskImpl.java:147)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.doCall(JavacTaskImpl.java:100)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.call(JavacTaskImpl.java:94)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.javac.JavaxToolsCompiler.compileInProcess(JavaxToolsCompiler.java:126)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.javac.JavacCompiler.performCompile(JavacCompiler.java:174)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.AbstractCompilerMojo.execute(AbstractCompilerMojo.java:1129)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.CompilerMojo.execute(CompilerMojo.java:188)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:192)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:347)
```

Comment: You need to `import java.util.EnumSet;`

Comment: @StephenC yes that was the mistake I have corrected now, updated error message as well.

Comment: this is indeed a problem with jmh - even the latest one built from sources. report a bug

Comment: @Eugene reported this to jmh-dev, see link of discussion in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Reported this problem to jmh-dev group, it turned out my mistake taking argument in Benchmark method.

To follow this discussion see link:

https://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/jmh-dev/2020-March/002935.html

Also they have added support to show error message rather than throwing exception.

Comment: It's good to see a proper error message for this. Thx for posting